# The smallest sequence without differences among Fibonacci numbers

Tags: integer-sequences, fibonacci-numbers

Given a subset $\mathcal S\subset \mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$
of (strictly) positive integers, we can consider subsets
$A$ of $\mathbb N$ (or $\mathbb Z$) with no differences in
$\mathcal S$.

Examples: If $\mathcal S=1+2\mathbb N$ we can take
$A=2\mathbb N$. If $\mathcal S=(2n)^{\mathbb N}=\lbrace
1,2n,(2n)^2,\ldots\rbrace$,
we can take for $\mathcal A$ all integers in the
classes of $0,2,4,\ldots,2n-2 \pmod{2n+1}$.

If $\mathcal S=\mathcal F=\lbrace
1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,\ldots\rbrace$
is the set of Fibonacci numbers, the greedy algorithm
(which adds iteratively the smallest possible element)
starting with $0$ yields
$$A=\lbrace
0,4,10,14,20,24,30,36,40,46,50,56,60,66,72,76,82,\ldots\rbrace
\ .$$
(This sequence is missing in the OEIS, the sequence augmented by $1$ coincides with A314043 up to $56+1=57$ before differing
by $1$ on $60+1=61<62$.)

Denoting by
$a_1=0<a_2=4<a_3=10<\ldots$ the increasing sequence
underlying $\mathcal A$, the graph of the function
$i\longmapsto \frac{a_i}{i}$ for $i=400,\ldots,12000$
is given by

[[image: <span class=]$i\longmapsto \frac{a_i}{i},i=400\ldots 12000$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hpHX.gif)

This suggests perhaps the existence of a limit-density
of $\mathcal A$ as a subset of $\mathbb N$.

Multiplicities in gap-sizes of the increasing sequence
$a_1,a_2,\ldots$ define
the gap-size polynomial $G(N)=\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}t^{a_{i+1}-a_i}$.
We get
$$G(1000)=354t^4+553t^6+8t^7+9t^9+42t^{10}+t^{11}+11t^{12}+t^{14}
+2t^{15}+9t^{16}+\ldots+t^{28}$$
and
$$G(10000)=3445t^4+5467t^6+40t^7+57t^9+498t^{10}+10t^{11}+121t^{12}+\ldots+t^{54}$$
indicating perhaps also
some sort of limit frequencies for gap-sizes.

A final observation is the rarity of odd elements in
$\mathcal A$: only 97 of the first $10000$ elements
in $\mathcal A$ are odd. (For $n$ an odd number, elements of
$A$ seem to be more ore less equidistributed modulo $n$.)

*Is there an explanation for these (empirical) observations
or are they artefacts?*

Comment: Intuitively, it seems that the rarity of odd elements can be explained by the fact that two thirds of Fibonacci numbers are odd. This gives a bias towards even numbers at the start, and that bias then self-reinforces.

Comment: Nice observation! Thanks.

Comment: Starting from the second term $4$ and up to $128$ the sequence coincides with $2$ times [OEIS A182771](https://oeis.org/A182771) i.e. $2\lfloor n(6+\sqrt{3})/3 \rfloor$.

Comment: @FabiusWiesner The sequence contains odd terms (169 is the first odd term). It is therefore different.

Comment: This can be thought of in terms of a two-player game called a [*subtraction game*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtraction_game), where given a set $S\subset\mathbf N$ called the *subtraction set*, two players have a heap of $n$ tokens between them, and are able to remove $s$ tokens during their turn for some $s\in S$; the last player to move is then the winner. The set $A$ in question is then the set of *cold positions* of this game when $S=\mathcal F$; that is, the set of numbers $n$ such that first player in a game of $n$ tokens can never win under optimal play.

Comment: Also, this problem has been studied when $S$ is the set of squares — Furstenberg and Sárközy proved that [square-difference-free sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-difference-free_set) have [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) equal to zero. The game version of this is then the [subtract-a-square game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtract_a_square), and the greedy set corresponding to this game is given by OEIS [A030193](https://oeis.org/A030193), which begins 0, 2, 5, 7, 10, 12, 15, 17, 20, 22, 34, 39, 44, 52, … .

Comment: Ah, okay; this problem has been studied before under the name Fibonacci nim (confusingly, since there are two nim variations with this name, and we are interested in the less popular one). See Jeremy C. Pond and Donald F. Howells, [“More on Fibonacci Nim”](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/3-1/pond.pdf), *Fibonacci Quarterly* **1** (3) (1963), 61–62, where it is proven that the density of $A$ is at most $1/5$. Unfortunately, I could not find any literature citing this work or investigating this topic further.

Comment: @hoboonsuan Thanks for these informations. By the way, density at most 1/5 is easy: Two consecutive terms of the sequence are at least at distance 4, never at distance 5 and since 4+4=8 is a Fibonacci number, three consecutive elements have diameter at least 10. This yields a density of at most 1/5 (in fact, one can easily lower the bound somewhat).

Comment: Oh, it is on the OEIS if you remove the first 0 in the sequence: https://oeis.org/A001581